# ASP.NET MVC and Spring.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, frameworks, spring.net

Starting a new project and would like to use one of the MVC framworks.  [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) is still in preview but [Spring.net](http://springframework.net/) is in production and has a history with Java.  I'd like to know the general lowdown between the two.

Current questions..
What are the major feature differences?
What about deployment/hosting issues?
Future support? Do you think Spring.net will fade once ASP.NET MVC is in production.
Current Support?  I saw the Jeff twitting about a breaking change in the next preview.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a little confused by the question.  Spring.Net is a dependency injection framework that you can use in ASP.NET MVC.  I kind of based my answer off what you are actually asking though.  The difference between ASP.NET MVC and another MVC framework that runs in ASP.NET.

If you are worried about using ASP.NET MVC in production since it is not even in beta yet, then you may want to check out [MonoRail](http://www.castleproject.org/MonoRail/) as an alternate.  There are some differences in features, but the two are pretty close in terminology and how MVC is implemented.  To learn differences, [here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165/from-monorail-to-aspnet-mvc) that was posted, that you might want to monitor.  I think once ASP.NET hits release, that most Microsoft shops will switch to it.  With ASP.NET MVC still being developed, you will run into breaking changes that you will have to change when you upgrade to the next release.  That goes with the territory of living on the edge.  You just need to read the release notes before jumping to the latest release.

Comment: thanks for the information. If i click on the link of mono rail, it says the castle project site is having malware. Is it true?

Comment: @PriyankThakkar Yes, I'm seeing the same thing now. Not sure what is up. It didn't have that when I posted the link. Here's the [Github account](https://github.com/castleproject).

Answer (score 1):

I have an impression that Spring.NET never really took off, or at least not as much as [Castle Project Monorail](http://www.castleproject.org/MonoRail/).

From what I understand, Spring.NET has also departed from Java Spring's implementation, so there will a steeper than expected learning curve if you are coming from Java. From [Spring.NET's overview](http://springframework.net/overview.html):

> The design of Spring.NET is based on
>   the Java version of the Spring
>   Framework, which has shown real-world
>   benefits and is used in thousands of
>   enterprise applications world wide. 
>   Spring .NET is not a quick port from
>   the Java version, but rather a
>   'spiritual port' based on following
>   proven  architectural and design
>   patterns in that are not tied to a
>   particular platform.

As for your other questions, the breadth of the topics make them a bit difficult to answer in one go, but I am hoping Phil Haack will see this question and respond. :)

Comment: You are thinking of Castle Windsor, not Castle Monorail (an MVC framework).

Answer (score 1):

Yes Spring.net adds enterprise solutions to Microsoft's codebase, Spring will fill the crucial missing gaps.

I can attempt to answer your question on future support of Spring.net & ASP.net MVC.  Apparently Spring will be releasing a new Milestone build when Microsoft go RTM/Final build:

http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?p=14031#post14031  (Mark is the Spring.net lead and a Microsoft MVP)

I've heard they don't want to give anything away until then, as they've had enough of Microsoft taking Springs ideas with no recognition.

Current Support for Spring.net & Controller Dependency Injection can be found in [MVCContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib)